# provide an initial solution to the genetic ordering algorithm

Tags: r, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I am using `ga()` function of `GA` package in `R` to find the best order.

I am wondering how do I provide an initial solution/population to the ga() function. I want don't want the algorithm to try out every possible combination. That is why I want to give an initial solution to it.

Here is an example of a problem I am working on (it is just an example, very straightforward).

```
library(GA)

f <-function(z) sum((z-c(1:4))^2)  # best order is 1, 2, 3, 4

result <- ga(type="permutation", fitness=f,
         min=1, max=4, names=paste0("pizza",1:4), maxiter = 100, popSize = 100)

summary(result)$solution
```

I want to give a starting solution say, `(3,2,1,4) or (4,2,1,3)` and want the algorithm to improve from that point. How do I do it here?

Documentation is not very clear. If this package can't be used for my specific problem and what other package should I use (am example would be great)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you can use 'suggestions' to provide a matrix of solutions to the algorithm.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GA/GA.pdf

Otherwise you can implement your own GA or extend the existing one by adding the needed by you methods.